# Finding time required to predict eact test image

Tags: keras

I am using LSTM model in Keras for image classification. While predicting the test images, I want to record the time required (in ms) to predict each test image. What are the ways to do that?

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the time difference in Python, we use the time module.

```
import time

t1 = time.time()
model.predict( ... )
# Testing has finished 
t2 = time.time()
print( 'Time taken was {} seconds'.format( t2 - t1))
```

For a Jupyter notebook, place this tag in the beginning of the cell.

```
%%time
```

**If suppose prediction of 10 images takes 3 seconds or 3000 milliseconds, then for 1 image the time will be 300 milliseconds or 0.3 second. This could be seen as a *rough estimate***

Comment: Problem is that I need to to get the time consumption for each image. One idea is to take each test image and predict them separately. In that case, the above answer is good. But if I want to send all the test images together to the predict function, then I will get the prediction time for all the images, not each one.

Comment: You can divide the time taken by the number of images. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think every image takes the same time to get classified.

Comment: The testing of each image is internal in keras and hence the calculation of time could not be possible. The above method could give a rough estimate if the images are of same size.